# Plotting a graph in R that features several dependent values for every independent sample point

Tags: r, data-visualization

A class has 40 students. Each student has submitted 14 homework assignments. Each submission was given a grade in the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, with 5 being the grade given to excellent submissions and 1 - to poor submissions. How can I model this scenario in R and how can I plot a graph showing students on the horizontal axis and their respective grades on the vertical axis?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "model this scenario"? (The question about graph plotting is off-topic here: see our [help] for more information about that.)

Comment: @whuber: Quoting from [one of the posts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the help center page: "If you have a question about [...] visualizing data, [...] statistical and data-driven computing then you're in the right place."

'Model this scenario' means: what data structures should I use that will be most amenable to plotting the data.

Comment: A question that cannot be understood or answered except within a particular computing platform is considered too narrow to be on-topic here and should instead be posted in an appropriate help forum. Thus, if there is a part of this question that could be considered that general, it would help to point it out.

Comment: @whuber: What forum then can I use to ask questions about modeling and visualizing data using R?

Comment: Stackoverflow would be that forum, I imagine. Yet your question is not clearly defined. How do you imagine plotting students on the x-axis, simply by index? You'll get a rather meaningless cloud of dots, I imagine. When you say "model", what kind of model do you have in mind? Describing the distribution of grades is not a model. I think you need to depart from a certain question, e.g. "Have the grades changed throughout the course?".